# Jenkins groovy Prompt with choices parameters based

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a nodenames that is going to be changing in a variable with each node on each line for example:

```
node1
node2
node3
```

The node will be assigned to variable, but because the node name will be dynamic am looking for way that the prompt will ask the user to choose from the chocie node 1 or node 2 or node 3 in the params

For example

```
def choosenode(nodename) {
    def nodechosen = input(
            id: 'userInput',
            message: 'Choose:',
            parameters: [[
                                 $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                 choices    : nodename.join("\n"),
                                 description: 'choosing node during prompt',
                                 name       : 'nodename'
                         ]]
    )
    return nodechosen
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like below?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def nodechosen = input message: 'Choose', ok: 'Next',
                                    parameters: [choice(name: 'Node', choices: gerNodeNames(), description: 'Select something')]
                                    
                    node(nodechosen) {
                        echo "Running in Selected node"
                    }
                   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

def gerNodeNames() {
    // Dummy code to create a file with node names
    sh "echo 'node1' >> nodeList.txt"
    sh "echo 'node2' >> nodeList.txt"
    sh "echo 'node3' >> nodeList.txt"
    
    // Reading the file
    def data = readFile(file: 'nodeList.txt')
    
    return data
}
```

Comment: The node 1 node 2 node 3 should not be hardcoded. Basivally, what is happening us that the script get the names of each standy in the db and list them in that format. I want to be able to select based on the values of the variables...

Comment: @user5820327 So you want to read the node names from a file?

Comment: Yes in a file preferably

Comment: @user5820327 check the updated answer, basically, you can implement `gerNodeNames()` to read the list from anywhere. After reading you can either return a `List` or a `String` each element separated with a `/n` to the Choice parameter.

Comment: you are a gem. Thanks alot. It works as I can returned each one now to the node         stage('Stage_Node') {
         
     sh " echo  "${params.Node}"  " 
            
        node ("${params.Node}") {   
            
        }
} when selected which makes the poc good for me